# how do you define a json object with attributes correctly?

Tags: json

I want to create a JSON object for customers, with attributes like "name" or address. I'm thinking of 2 ways of doing that, I don't understand which one is the standard one:

```
1. "members": [{"name":"TheCustomerName":"address":"theAddress","otherAttribute":""},{....}]

2. "members": [{"TheCustomerName":{"address":"theAddress","otherAttribute":""},{...}]
```

Basically, do I need to have an attribute calle "name" or not

Comment: go with the first one so you won't have to deal with dynamic member names : `json[0].somethingThatWillVary.address` vs `json[0].address`

Comment: In fact the second one is missing a closing Bracke.